# REST PathParam with Multiple Types

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've got a REST service set up to access information stored in a database.

I'd like to be able to access based on either an item's `id` or `name`.

So lets say I've got a record

```
name | id | description
mine | 65 | "my thing"
```

I'd like to be able to access this item through either:

```
myurl.com/items/65
myurl.com/items/mine
```

I'm using Jersey (Java library). Is there a way I can define the PathParam to accept either an int or a String WITHOUT using object.typeOf()?

I'd like to avoid this:

```
@PATH("/items/{identifier}
@GET
public String getItem(@PathParam("identifier") Object identifier){
     if(identifier.typeOf().equals(String.typeOf()))....
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `.class` instead of `.typeOf()`?

Comment: I was just free forming the typeOf() bit.  Mike's answer below shows the correct Java syntax for that.  Good catch though.  Thanks!

Comment: Jochen mentioned this below but it's worth emphasizing: This whole scheme is doomed to failure if it's possible to use "4711" as a name. So make sure that can't happen! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a "clean" solution - I don't think there is one. But you could do this:

```
@PATH("/items/{identifier}")
public String getItem(@PathParam("identifier") String identifier){
   try {
       return getByID( Long.parseLong(identifier) );
   } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
       return getByName( identifier );
   }
}
```

Also, this won't compile - there's no such method as `typeOf()`:

```
if(identifier.typeOf().equals(String.typeOf()))
```

I think you meant:

```
if (identifier instanceof String)
```

---

**EDIT**: And anyway, your original idea (setting the parameter type to `Object`, then checking for the exact instance type) won't work; the container has no way of knowing that the path element may be an integer, so it won't attempt to parse it as an integer, and it'll just give you a `String` every time.

Comment: +1 using string and parsing a long if needed is the cleanest way of doing it.

Comment: Great idea on attempting to parse out a `Long`.  Thanks!